# How to make xcode generated CoreData model class to use NSInteger for int32 column?

Tags: iphone

Seems silly to me that it generates NSNumber when I specify the column as int. This makes calculations and updates tedius... 
e.g. x = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:([x intValue] + 1)];

There is the "use primitive types" checkbox, but it uses char array instead of NSString, which is not what I want.

So is it possible to tell it to generate NSInteger? If if I manually change the code to use NSInteger, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

CoreData uses `NSNumber` because of the extra support given by having an object wrapper around primitive types (serialisation, KVO, etc.). See the comment at the bottom of [this page](http://objcolumnist.com/2009/05/31/nsnumber-what-is-the-point/).

If having to mess around with `NSNumber` objects annoys you, write (or search for) an `NSNumber` category that does some of the grunt work for you. For example, you could write a category that implements basic arithmetic operations `add:(int)x`.